# update child's parentcategoryId if parentcategoryId itself  dont  have any  parent and  any products?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, loops

First of all i have to those categoryIDs

```
1-whos parentcategoryID only appears one 
2-ParentCategoryID is not zero
3-IsProduct =0
```

[image: sql scrren shot]

in above picture only 4 `categoryId` satisfy all these three conditions.

Now i have to  update those categories who parent is 4 with ParentCategoryID in my case is 2.

i can do this for single row but if there are multiple `categoryId` who satisfy these three conditions then i have to make a loop for this or i can do this with `;with cte` but i not getting how to write code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have miss understood what you are asking I think the below will perform the update required. In the data you have given this would update rows 4 & 6. I have tried to comment the where clause in the subquery to match the criteria you listed.

```
UPDATE  yourTable
SET     ParentCategoryID = upd.CategoryID
FROM    yourTable tab
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  CategoryID, tab.ParentCategoryID
            FROM    yourTable tab
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    (   SELECT  ParentCategoryID
                        FROM    yourTable
                        GROUP BY ParentCategoryID
                        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1        
                    ) dupe
                        ON dupe.ParentCategoryID = tab.ParentCategoryID
            WHERE   dupe.ParentCategoryID IS NULL   -- 1. PARENT ID DOES NOT EXIST MORE THAN ONCE
            AND     tab.ParentCategoryID != 0       -- 2. PARENT ID IS NOT 0
            AND     IsProduct = 0                   -- 3. ISPRODUCT = 0
            GROUP BY CategoryID, tab.ParentCategoryID
        ) upd
            ON upd.CategoryID = tab.ParentCategoryID
```

Comment: i want that row number 4 and 6's value of  ParentCategoryId column should be replaced by 2 as there parent 4 have ParentCategoryId!=0 and IsProduct=0 and 4's parentCategoryId which is 2 appears only once in this table

Comment: Then the query I have supplied will work exactly as intended. There is no need to use a loop or CTE. There is potential for this to run into difficulty, but given your criteria I this is unavoidable whatever method you use. If you had an additional row in your data with a ParentCategoryID = 5, IsProduct = 1 and CategoryID = 4, this would also fulfil your criteria and would want to update rows 4 and 6 but it is ambiguous as to whether this should update to 4 (from row 2) or to 5 (from the new row). This does not apply if categoryID is constrained to be unique